# Form spanning over multiple pages in iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I've made a form in the PDF document and all works well. However, when the content of the document extends over to the second page, the form fields are applied to the second page instead of the first page where the table is.

If I switch the statement `writer.addAnnotation(form)` to a line before the content that causes the creation of the second page, then all's fine. However, if I add it to the end of the document, this form is applied on the second page.

Is there any way to overcome this? Is there a method I'm missing that allows me to set the page to which the form is applied?

Additionally, I wish to keep one single form that spans across multiple pages with paragraphs between the fields.

Comment: *Is there any way to overcome this?* - you mean essentially whether it is possible to add form elements after having created most of the pdf. You can do this by **not** adding the Form fields to the PdfWriter at all but instead working on the created pdf using a PdfReader/PdfStamper combination. The stamper allows you to put form fields on any page of the PDF read by the reader.

Comment: I shall try that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method of overcoming this is by adding each field to the document as and when they're created instead of adding the entire form at the end of the document as shown in the examples.

Comment: Yes, but your question sounded as if you wanted to avoid that.

Comment: I should have been more specific. Then again, I didn't know that this was possible.